# Search box engine in PHP that outputs images from CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I'm new to programming in php.  I was wondering how I could create a text search box engine for my website that would pull a list of types of dogs from a CSV file.  So, let's say a user enters into the text box, Poodle, the output in my web browser would be all the poodles listed in the column 'Category' in my csv file.  I don't want to use SQL for this.  How would I create the form, so the user could search by category and output the images of these dogs to my web browser?  So far, I have the following code written, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track and how I would create the search engine?

```
 $dogcategories = array();

 $fp = fopen('dogcategories.csv', 'r');
 $headers = fgetcsv($fp);
 while ($x = fgetcsv($fp)) {
     $dog[] = array_combine($headers, $x);
 }
 fclose($fp);

 foreach($allDogcategories = array();

 foreach($dogcategories as $row) {
     $allDogcategories[] = $row['Category'];
 }

 $allDogcategories = array_unique($allDogcategories);

 foreach($allDogcategories as $key => $category) {
     echo '<li><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'? category = '.$key.'">'.$category.'</a></li>';
 }

 if (isset($_GET['category']) && array_key_exists($_GET['category'], $allDogcategories)) {
     $SelectedDogCatagory = $_GET['category'];
 }

 foreach($dogcategories as $array) {
     if (isset($SelectedDogCatagory) && $allDogcategories[$SelectedDogCategory] !== $array['Category']) {
         continue;
     }

     echo ' < a href = "'.$array['Img'].'" > < img src = "'.$array['IMG jpg'].'"
     width = "140"
     height = "140"
     alt = "'.$array['ALT'].'"
     longdesc = "'.$array['IMG link'].'" / > < /a> < h4 > '.$array['Name of Dog '].' < /h4>';
 }

 echo '<form method="GET" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">';
 echo '<h1>Search Categories</h1>';
 echo '<BR>';
 echo '<input type="text" name="search">'.' ';
 echo '<input type="submit" name="searchButton" value="Search">';
 echo '<BR>';
 echo '</form>';
```

Comment: why not use a real database for this?

Comment: It's for a class project and we are only allowed to use csv at this time.